# Having Tag lost Issues Reading ISO 14443 Type B using NFC through Android

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, contactless-smartcard

I'm trying to read SO 14443 Type B using NFC through Android,

It is taking quite a long time to detect the card and most of the time getting transceiver failed and Tag is getting lost.

But not facing any issues with Type A cards.

I'm trying using Android Foreground dispatch approach,Tried using Samsung S3 and S4 as well to make sure the Android API has any Issues.

I tried with different NFC controllers NXP PN544 and Broadcom BCM20794  in different phone also getting the same response.

I'm unable to conclude whether we have maximum  Power Intensity of the NFC antenna to power the PICC antenna

Is there any solution to work about for the Type B cards